# Você não vai com a minha cara?

Tags: debate, voto-contra

Parece piada, mas realmente parece que há uma galerinha que gosta de dar negativo pelo simples prazer de não ir com a cara de alguém.

Já sinalizei, já falei em comentários, já falei no chat, mas não adianta. Esses carinhas que apertam o botãozinho que fica em baixo do número da reputação sempre voltam!

Recebi votos negativos inexplicáveis por essas perguntas:

[Uma imagem base64 carrega mais rápido que uma url?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95119/uma-imagem-base64-carrega-mais-r%C3%A1pido-que-uma-url) (-2)

[Diferença entre "list(range(1, 10))" e "range(1, 10)"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95184/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-listrange1-10-e-range1-10) (-1)

E por essa resposta:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/95094/4995 (-1, inclusive foi marcada como resposta útil)

Ainda fico tendo aquela curiosidade: O que tem de errado com minha resposta, hein? Mas nunca há comentários. Eu sei, já falaram em outro post aqui que algumas pessoas têm medo de retaliações por parte de pessoas que não aceitam votos negativos.

Se a pergunta ou resposta merece negativo, tudo bem. Mas se ela (no caso a resposta) até mesmo marcada como resposta útil, por que ainda estou recebendo votos negativos?

É por isso que estou questionando isso aqui: Você não vai com minha cara, downvoter? É esse o motivo de receber negativo, algo pessoal?

E deixo aqui a foto do Quico pois quero expressar minha indignação, mas ao mesmo tempo rir da situação, pois já está passando do limite do ridículo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se essa situação continuar, estou declarando greve de votos. kkkkk

Comment: Vai chover negativos aqui, estou esperando isso. Só espero que todos gostem de Chaves

Comment: Ja já expresso minha opinião sobre, agora estou sem tempo = D

Comment: Negativo uma resposta que foi ruim, pouco fez questão de resolver a pergunta, colocou qualquer resposta e a gente ganha um -1 junto com o cara. Sei que não tem a ver com o que você falou já que se trata de um -1 merecido de verdade nesse caso, ao contrário do que você mencionou.

Comment: Só mais uma coisa: Não façam efeito manada nas minhas perguntas e respostas como de costume, quando algo é postado aqui. É só uma indignação, e não um pedido de votos. É um pedido de justiça!

Comment: Se forem só essas 2 questões o problema, então tudo está normal. Eu também tenho questões com votos negativos, quem não tem? Só tens esses exemplos?

Comment: Ia dar -1 aqui mas achei que era demais ;)

Comment: @JorgeB., essas são só exemplos. Tem outras que receberam votos inexplicáveis. Não tenho tempo pra procurar agora. Estou trabalhando (a foto é do Quico, não a do Seu Madruga, kkkkkkk)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters mas tens de informar isso na questão, nem toda a gente sabe que te aconteceu isso.

Comment: Entendi. Valeu, depois edito

Comment: O negativismo é nocivo não só no SO. Agora me diga uma coisa, para que sofrer com isso, todo cara que lança um negativo, no mínimo está tentando se vingar de outro voto negativo que recebeu de outrem, só para se sentir recompensado. É uma bola de neve e uma atitude de gente derrotista que repete essa mesmice. Gostei que tenha expressado a sua opinião contra. +1 para você.

Comment: Yes! Meta drama! Da minha parte, nada pessoal :)

Comment: @IvanFerrer, obrigado pelas suas palavras. Estou ouvindo um heavy metal que está me acalmando. O problema de "sair por um tempo" é que não são só minhas perguntas, minhas respostas também agora estão recebendo negativos da "vingancinha". Talvez eu deva sair por 1 ano, kkkkkk

Comment: Hoje vocês podem me dar -1, só não dêem -1 para o Quico

Comment: Na minha opnião deveriam tirar o -1, ficasse apenas o +1. Os ruins ficam com 0 mesmo rsrs as vezes o -1 é utilizado desnecessariamente, por exemplo nesse caso, em outros casos em perguntas de novatos. Se a pergunta ou é resposta são ruins, ficam com 0 mesmo igual nota de prova.

Comment: @Giancarlo, -1 é o controle de qualidade básico do site, se tem gente que usa de maneira equivocada só vai ser um problema se for uma avalanche de equívocos (até agora não tem evidência disso aqui no SOpt). Se alguém quer um site sem -1 pode criar um grupo de auto-ajuda no Facebook onde só vale energia positiva.

Comment: Cara, eu acho que tem vários fatores aí: retaliação (mesmo injustificada), inveja (da sua rep), gamification, e por aí vai. Acho que quando a pessoa não vai mesmo com a sua cara ela já entra na pergunta procurando defeitos. Daí ai que a pessoa tem um grande conhecimento, e nesta pergunta por exemplo, imagino algo assim: "Ah, o cara com 10k de rep! Como assim se é mais rápido ou não? Vai testar!"... Acho que quando sua rep aumenta e vc faz muitas perguntas (e seu caso é um extremo da coisa...), algumas pessoas acabam considerando que vc não deveria apresentar perguntas sobre problemas reais ...

Comment: Apenas perguntas em tese, e de preferência aquela minúcia da minúcia... só para enriquecer o conhecimento, e gerar o desafio pelo qual todos estão aqui (SQN)... O link da pergunta citada acima: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95119/uma-imagem-base64-carrega-mais-r%C3%A1pido-que-uma-url (excedeu os caractres na anterior)...

Comment: Já tens um -1 aqui ;)

Comment: @brasofilo, a rede social em que trabalho, tem apenas a opção de "curtir" ou  "desfazer curtir" um post. E ainda acho que deveria ter um "negativos". Até o site "Os vigaristas" você pode pontuar se uma piada foi ruim ou não. Então é sempre bom mesmo terem os negativos :)

Comment: Em tempo: é claro que votei positivo na pergunta que mencionei né, pq em geral as perguntas do Wallace são ótimas imho... e esta especificamente imagino que vá me ser útil em algum momento ... obviamente que não tava falando de mim, que ainda sei só um pouco de quase nada.

Comment: Pior que receber um -1 é receber uma enxurrada de -3 de gente que nem se preocupou em saber se realmente a questão merecia aquele -1. Nossa sorte é que o tempo as vezes melhora, e faz o índice subir naturalmente por que tem boas pessoas ainda que reconhecem que houve uma injustiça.

Comment: Eu, particularmente, tenho muito prazer em arrancar o -1 das pessoas e subir com +1, e faço isso quando vejo que a pergunta é boa.

Comment: Interessante é que o apelo ao moderador para não remover a foto foi tirado, kkkkkkk

Comment: @gustavox, fora quando você recebe uma porrada de negativos por sua "pergunta burra", e todo mundo que responde ganha uma enxorada de positivos.

Comment: Wallace, fique a vontade para colocar de volta, mas não será esse pedido que vai impedir um mod de tirar a foto, mas não vejo motivo nenhum pra fazer isso (pelo menos é o que acho)

Comment: Eu sei, foi só um comentário atoa

Comment: @brasofilo Não estava me referindo a você, desconheço os critérios que você usa para votar. Esses caras a quem eu estava me referindo não se limitavam apenas a downvotes para limpar lixo, faziam muitas outras coisas negativas além disso (e devem fazer até hoje), por vezes dando downvotes em contúdos considerados bons por outros usuários só por discordarem e dizendo que estavam no direito de fazer isso. Por outro lado, eu recomendaria você a se esforçar mais nos upvotes para promover o conteúdo bom e incentivar os bons usuários, pois o número de thumbleweeds e unsung heros está excessivo no SO.

Comment: @Victor, pois é, eu tenho fetiche em limpar lixo. Tá cheio de gente que gosta de flores e upvotes. Estamos no mesmo time? Acho lindo encontrar bons conteúdos e votar positivamente, você reconhece meu papel de lixeiro que tenta manter a cidade limpa para usufruto alheio?

Comment: @brasofilo Estamos no mesmo time. Reconheço seu papel.

Comment: @Victor, é que merece um estudo sociológico! - Porquê a rede Stack Overflow é bem sucedida? - Por que tem uma moderação radical da própria comunidade. - E qual o efeito dessa moderação? - Muito descontentamento das massas inquisidoras e uma base permanente de gente boa de serviço com disposição pra responder. . . . . . Se isto fosse Yahoo Respostas, ia ter boas respostas? Ia ser fácil achar uma resposta imediata pra seu problema estranho? Os bons profissionais iam passar o dia aqui procurando boas perguntas pra responder? Pois então, -1 na cabeça, sem dó.

Comment: @brasofilo Eu entendo como funcionam os downvotes e os upvotes e sei porque isso daqui não é Yahoo Respostas. O problema não é ter o poder de dar o -1, o problema é gente que utiliza isso incorretamente, insiste em usar incorretamente e tem poder para usar incorretamente. Esses que eu estava falando, embora não fossem no StackOverflow, já vi postando comentários deixando bem claro que estavam dando downvote porque não sabiam a resposta ou porque não dava para usar o produto que eles ajudaram a desenvolver e promoviam na resposta. Enfim, não era para ser desse jeito os sites da SE.

Comment: @VIctor, mas a mesma argumentação pode ser usada pros upvotes! Como posso saber se aquela resposta é boa mesmo ou se é só "empolgação" e "yahoo"?

Comment: @brasofilo Aliás, o upvote mal dado me assusta mais que o downvote mal dado. E faz mais estrago, na minha humilde opinião.

Comment: @bacco, Também acho up vote de “rebanho” mais nocivo que downvote.   Normalmente a galera dá upvote em comentários, perguntas e respostas de membros com alta pontuação , alta popularidade ou elevados privilégios, sem realmente prestar atenção se está mesmo certo ou errado.

Comment: @DanielOmine infelizmente acho que o problema não se restringe a grupos específicos, eu vejo valorização em postagens ruins de todas as origens, seja resposta ruim "enfeitada", o só por usarem discursos prontos de "boas práticas", ou por mero "parece legal isso aqui". O problema central é o voto de quem não analisa e/ou não entende a postagem, e suas consequências para quem vai ler aquilo no futuro.

Comment: Olha só: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1916/132

Comment: imagina se um downvote consumisse 10 reputações para faze-lo. pessoal ia ficar mais ligado antes de fazer isso rs

Comment: Eu tinha abandonado esse site porque eu percebi que as minhas respostas estavam sendo negativas pelo simples fato de que as perguntas que elas estavam respondendo também estavam sendo negativadas. Quando eu questionei a razão disto, passaram a perseguir outras respostas minhas pra negativar também.

Comment: Hoje eu li todo o meta sobre votos negativos e concluí que esse site é um caso perdido. As pessoas que fundaram o site encheram o saco dele e ao invés de pararem de usar, transformaram num lugar ruim. Provavelmente nem se dão conta de como destruíram a reputação do site e forçaram as pessoas a migrar pra alternativas - muitas delas superam os resultados de buscas e as referências. Ainda que eu tivesse o tempo e a motivação pra criar comunidade e "tomar conta" desse site, influenciando a cultura, já não vale mais a pena na minha opinião.

Comment: @PauloRobertoRosa em alguns sites da rede isso é verdade, quando tu dá um voto negativo, tu também perde reputação. Eu acredito que voto negativo é uma coisa muito importante e deve ser usado de forma repsonsável, então apoio esse requisito de ter que pagar em reputação pra poder diminuir a reputação dos outros

Answer (score 19):

"Você" quem, cara-pálida?
Duvido muito que quem votou negativo ali venha aqui se explicar e dizer "é, não vou com sua cara...".

Mas vou quebrar seu galho e revelar quem são. São [seus fãs Número Um](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annie_Wilkes).

Sua resposta tem 9 votos positivos, que, em teoria, são porque é uma solução útil e bem explicada. Tem um negativo sem explicação ou justificativa aparente. O mais provável é que seja o fã que não se importa em perder 1 ponto de reputação só para te provocar:

[image]

O outro que não quer perder pontos mas quer te negativar acho que é este:

[image]

A grande pergunta é, *como conseguiu esses fãs?*
Provavelmente, você criticou ou apontou erros em algum post (pergunta ou resposta) e o usuário levou de maneira pessoal. Esse é basicamente o maior equívoco de muitos usuários: a gente critica o ***post***, o **conteúdo** (ou falta de), vota negativamente se for o caso, e isso é tomado como uma crítica à própria pessoa, como uma grave ofensa pessoal capaz de iniciar uma guerra atômica.

Sua contribuição ao site já passa dos dez mil pontos de reputação, parabéns, esse é um grande momento! Tens acesso privilegiado a ferramentas de moderação do site. Mas a estas alturas já devia ter o couro mais curtido, se seus fãs conseguem te provocar uma greve de voto, então eles ganharam.

---

PS: se está sofrendo uma sequência de votos negativos não-justificados (em termos de qualidade dos seus posts), sinalize um dos posts e peça atenção dos moderadores.

Comment: Concordo. Essa primeira imagem é daquele filme da doida que sequestra um escritor?

Comment: "da doida" não, por favor, é a Kathy Bates interpretando um clássico do Stephen King :D .. . . . O link tá ali no "seus fãs número um".

Comment: Hehe, eu tinha esquecido o nome dela. Ela é ótima, doida é a personagem.

Comment: jejeje, sim, sim, ela põe medo no fundo da alma do telespectador, mandou bem demais

Comment: Seguido de um `kkk` eu diria que a greve de voto foi um desabafo exagerado. E mais: Tenho costume de deixar um comentário quando negativo alguém. Deve ser por isso que fazem isso comigo!

Comment: Pq fas içu comigu, spoder?

Comment: Depois dessa declaração, eu meus votos já estão quase acabando. Não fui vingativo :)

Comment: @Wallace, esse tipo de vingança mesquinha é o preço de dar a cara quando faz -1 e explica o motivo. Uma dica importante é não se associar ao voto, ou seja, explica o que tem de errado mas sem dizer que votou.

Comment: @brasofilo, esse é o problema. Deve ter um tanto de comentário meu assim: "-1, essa resposta não responde a questão"

Comment: @brasofilo anda inspirado, vi uns comentários em perguntas de novatos que deveriam ser enlatados!

Comment: @Wallace, em linguagem de rua, isso se chama "colocar a bunda na janela" :P

Comment: Pode falar "bunda" aqui? kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk. Zueira, entendi o ditado

Comment: Isso é que vocês chamam de inspiração?

Comment: @Wallace, note que o gustavo fala de *perguntas de novatos*... pra veterano, o papo é outro, jeje

Comment: Quando comecei participar do sopt, eu critiquei e questionei perguntas simples por não compreender que eram aceitáveis. O tempo passou e de repente surge essa figura lendária , o wallace maxter, fazendo perguntas simples demais. No começo achei que ele fosse um tonto ou um mero caça medalha  rsrsrs..  Mas hoje vejo que ele éum dos maiores contribuidores da comunidade. São perguntas que geram sempre boas respostas e tira-se grande proveito. Acho que os que votam  negativo  talvez não compreendam que as perguntas simples sejam aceitáveis. Não creio que seja retaliação ou qq coisa outra coisa.

Answer (score 13):

Downvotes, para o bem ou para o mal, são parte do nosso site. E afetam todos, não só você.

Quanto mais você participar do site, mais você estará sujeito à eles, tanto os "devidos" quanto os "indevidos". Ambos os termos entre aspas porque julgá-los dessa maneira é virtualmente impossível, e ninguém pode fazê-lo.

Os moderadores estão constantemente de olho em qualquer padrão de comportamento que indique malícia no uso do site, de votos contra ou à favor, ou qualquer outro tipo de manipulação que possa ferir nossa comunidade.

Mas cada downvote, por si só... É apenas um downvote. Não é sinal de perseguição, picuinha, vingança ou algo do tipo. E o aumento de downvotes é um reflexo natural do aumento da sua participação e envolvimento no site. É normal, e parte da liberdade da comunidade.

O melhor, definitivamente, é pensar que mesmo esses downvotes, que você não sabe o motivo, vêm acompanhados de muito mais upvotes, muito mais expressões de que o que você vem produzindo está sendo útil e aproveitado por um grande número de pessoas.

Claro que os downvotes são um sinal de que pode haver algo errado e, como devs, querer resolver todos o problemas - no nosso código e nossos posts - é parte da nossa natureza. Mas não perca de vista que eles são só parte natural de expor suas opiniões, e não refletem a qualidade do que você vem fazendo.

Comment: acho que não é essa a questão.. ele não questiona o sistema de downvotes mas o comportamento e mal uso.

Comment: @DanielOmine eu falei sobre tudo isso....

Answer (score 11):

Desde o primeiro mês de vida do Stack Overflow em Português, por muito meses, tive problemas desse tipo. Já fui vítima de votos negativos em série e até de ameaças! Tive também atritos com alguns usuários, o que provavelmente foi a causa de muitos desses problemas.

Mas, acredite, o melhor que você pode fazer é ignorar, passar por cima de tudo isso e continuar sempre tendo a melhor participação que você puder, da forma mais positiva. Isso não quer dizer que tudo será perfeito, mas ajuda muito.

O maior atrito que já tive aqui hoje resultou em uma amizade, ainda que à distância. Então, quando você age positivamente com todos, é bem possível que um dia você acabe mudando a perspectiva de quem não gosta de você.

Por outro lado, algo que já me fez tomar votos negativos foi quando eu tentava responder toda e qualquer pergunta, mesmo quando não conhecia nada do assunto. No começo do site, quando tínhamos por volta de 10 perguntas diárias isso era possível. Então tem muita coisa ruim que acabei escrevendo.

Nesse sentido, hoje tenho pouquíssimos votos negativos pois foco nas coisas que tenho domínio e, se vejo que uma resposta não está ficando lá essas coisas, não tenho medo de descartá-la.

Comment: "Mas, acredite, o melhor que você pode fazer é ignorar" e "não tenho medo de descartá-la" foi essa maturidade que ganhei por aqui...

Comment: Muito bom! @JorgeB., tenho o mesmo sentimento

Comment: O cara foi ameaçado. Já me sinto um pouco melhor, já que não cheguei a esse ponto.